# chart.js - restart values on mouseover

Tags: javascript, charts

I using chart.js for display responsive data. Everything is working apart 1 thing... when my mouse is over the chart , chart load for 1st data..  Anybody know how to fix that issue??

Chart.js code i using:

```
$(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {

            x = 2328;
            y = 5567;
            z = 12334;
            loadChart();}, 1000 );

        $("#today").on('click',function(){
            x = 8;
            y = 7;
            z = 54;
            loadChart();
        });
    $("#yersterday").on('click',function(){
            x = 28;
            y = 37;
            z = 80;
            loadChart();
        });$("#month").on('click',function(){
            x = 178;
            y = 172;
            z = 824;
            loadChart();
        });$("#lastmonth").on('click',function(){
            x = 568;
            y = 507;
            z = 1214;
            loadChart();
        });
        function loadChart(){
        new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Deskop", "Tablet", "Mobile"],
                datasets: [
                {
                 label: "Page views",
                backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
                data: [x,y,z]
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Page views (since lunch)'
            }
            }
        });
    }


});
```

Generally i using ajax call to get json data content from database but to let you know my issue better i create fiddle:
So after you will change chart data and mouseover chart you will see what i mean.

fiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7yp4e3zj/8/)

And snipper:

```js
$(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
 
   x = 2328;
   y = 5567;
   z = 12334;
   loadChart();}, 1000 );
   
  $("#today").on('click',function(){
   x = 8;
   y = 7;
   z = 54;
   loadChart();
  });
    $("#yersterday").on('click',function(){
   x = 28;
   y = 37;
   z = 80;
   loadChart();
  });$("#month").on('click',function(){
   x = 178;
   y = 172;
   z = 824;
   loadChart();
  });$("#lastmonth").on('click',function(){
   x = 568;
   y = 507;
   z = 1214;
   loadChart();
  });
  function loadChart(){
  new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
         labels: ["Deskop", "Tablet", "Mobile"],
         datasets: [
          {
            label: "Page views",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [x,y,z]
          }
         ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Page views (since lunch)'
        }
      }
  });
 }


});
```

```css
[class*="col-"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
h5{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-8" style="height: 400px"><canvas id="bar-chart" width="100%" height="40px"></canvas></div>
   <div class="col-4" id="today" style="height: 50px" ><h5>today</h5></div>
   <div class="col-4" id="yersterday" style="height: 50px" ><h5>yersterday </h5></div>
   <div class="col-4" id="month" style="height: 50px" ><h5>this month</h5></div>
   <div class="col-4" id="lastmonth" style="height: 50px" ><h5>last month</h5></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy the previous chart. You can do this declaring a variable for the chart. See the the code below, the variable "myChart" does the magic.

```
$(function() {

        var myChart = null;

        setTimeout(function() {

        x = 2328;
        y = 5567;
        z = 12334;
        loadChart();}, 1000 );

    $("#today").on('click',function(){
        x = 8;
        y = 7;
        z = 54;
        loadChart();
    });
$("#yersterday").on('click',function(){
        x = 28;
        y = 37;
        z = 80;
        loadChart();
    });$("#month").on('click',function(){
        x = 178;
        y = 172;
        z = 824;
        loadChart();
    });$("#lastmonth").on('click',function(){
        x = 568;
        y = 507;
        z = 1214;
        loadChart();
    });
    function loadChart(){

// if the chart is not undefined (e.g. it has been created)
// then destory the old one so we can create a new one later
if (myChart) {
    myChart.destroy();
}

    myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Deskop", "Tablet", "Mobile"],
            datasets: [
            {
             label: "Page views",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [x,y,z]
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Page views (since lunch)'
        }
        }
    });
}


});
```